# How do I interpret and visualize lme4 linear mixed effects model (lmer) results?

Tags: r, statistical-significance, mixed-model, data-visualization, lme4-nlme

I have run a lmer model (lme4) and lmerTest to look at the relationship between Fraction of time spent in open arms (which represents Anxiety) and spine density. As I am relatively new to linear mixed effects models and R I was wondering if my (written and visual) interpretation is of the results is right. There are three ROIs: ACC, S1 and CA1, with ACC being the reference ROI.

**Model formula:** 
SpineDensity ~ Treatment + FractionTimeOpen * ROI + (1 | ROI) +  (1 | Group) + (1 | GroupRat)

**Based on the model results below my interpretation is:**

- Spine density in ​ACC (reference ROI) is significantly predicted by anxiety (p=0.00261). In ACC, lower spine density is found in rats with lower anxiety (slope=-1.30251).
- Anxiety affects spine density in ACC border-line significantly differently than in S1 (p= 0.05495). Spine density in S1 is higher with lower anxiety compared to spine density in ACC (slope=1.03756)
- There are no difference between FU exposed and control group as Treatment is not a significant predictor of the model (p=0.36305)

**[image: Model output in R]**

```
Fixed effects:
                         Estimate Std. Error        df t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)               2.45412    0.21713  49.74778  11.303 2.39e-15 ***
TreatmentFU Exposed      -0.09993    0.10390   8.39150  -0.962  0.36305    
FractionTimeOpen         -1.30251    0.40830  44.46290  -3.190  0.00261 ** 
ROICA1                   -0.06634    0.26690 113.42008  -0.249  0.80415    
ROIS1                    -0.12689    0.26187 111.35551  -0.485  0.62895    
FractionTimeOpen:ROICA1   0.88781    0.55070 114.39061   1.612  0.10968    
FractionTimeOpen:ROIS1    1.03756    0.53492 111.39834   1.940  0.05495 .  

Correlation of Fixed Effects:
            (Intr) TrtFUE FrctTO ROICA1 ROIS1  FTO:ROIC
TrtmntFUExp -0.340                                     
FractnTmOpn -0.432  0.057                              
ROICA1      -0.600  0.018  0.301                       
ROIS1       -0.603 -0.001  0.299  0.491                
FrTO:ROICA1  0.278 -0.027 -0.646 -0.482 -0.222         
FrcTO:ROIS1  0.276 -0.003 -0.656 -0.224 -0.458  0.487
```